# Javascript variable hoisting for gobal scope

Tags: javascript, variables

Can someone explain why undefined is printed to the console and not 4?

```
var a = 4;
function test() {
 if (!a) {
   a = 3;
 }
 console.log(a)
}
undefined
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with hoisting.

Comment: It returns as 4 if you put the console.log outside the function.

Comment: This would have been a hoisting related if 1) you hadn't defined `var a` outside the `test function` AND/OR 2) you had defiened another `var a` insider the `test function`

Comment: @KingKongFrog if you see the value of a by just writing **a** in console after executing your code it will show you even you can check it by executing **test()**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `variable hoisting`.

Because you haven't `return` anything. So, when you execute this code in browser console, it show `undefined`.

To get `4`, as result you need to call the `test` function and `return a` from the function.

Code:

```
var a = 4;

function test() {
    if (!a) {
        a = 3;
    }

    console.log(a);

    // Return a from the function, if needed
    return a;
}

// Call function here
test();
```